# Refreshing and Updating SSRS Parameters

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, cascading

I have a report with the following parameters:  License Type, Beginning Expiration Date, and End Expiration Date.  I have the query set up to return the correct expiration dates that are dependent on the License Type.  If I set up the Expiration date fields to use the query for the 'Available Values', it will correctly return the default date fields, but it will return the value as a date/time.  It will also not allow me to change the default dates to something else, if needed.  However, if I use the query in 'Default Values', it will display the date as a short date, will display the calendar control, and will allow me to modify the field as necessary.  However, the expiration date fields will not refresh when I change the value in the License Type parameter.  Is there a way to refresh my parameters and still be able to modify them?

Comment: Are you using cascading params? Use the value of the License Type in your sql for values for the date params. Set the date params as text. Make sure the correct values are coming through for the dates

Comment: I am using cascading parameters. I have created a dataset that should return the correct date, but I run into the problem described above.  I tried adding an additional parameter field that sets a default value in an intermediate step  that my Beginning Expiration Date field reads from  in the Default values.  That seems to work only if I keep the field visible.  If I hide it from being displayed, it won't refresh.